# problem for bind radiobutton to database

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

Please following my code :

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid_services, Path=SelectedItem}" 
 Width="766">
<RadioButton Content="visit" IsChecked="{Binding Path=type_services}"  
 FontFamily="Tahoma"/>
```

i want to bind ischecked property from radiobutton  but return value is not false or true.
the value is string. please help me how to bind this value?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an IValueConverter.

Given this window containing your radiobutton and associated bindings:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="dataGrid_services">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CheckedConverter x:Key="converter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid_services, Path=SelectedItem}"  Width="766">
    <RadioButton Content="visit" IsChecked="{Binding Path=type_services, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"   FontFamily="Tahoma"/>
</Grid>
```

The changes are adding a namespace reference for local (or whichever namespace your converter is in):

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

creating the converter resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CheckedConverter x:Key="converter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and using the converter resource:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=type_services, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"
```

The converter looks like this and simply converts from string to boolean.

```
public class CheckedConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string typeService = value as string;
            if (typeService == "Yes it is")
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (typeService == "Nope")
            {
                return false;
            }

        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool typeService = (bool)value;


            if (typeService)
            {
                return "Yes it is";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Nope";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i use this IValueConverter?

Comment: @mo_al - you need to define it as a resource and then reference it (as a StaticResource} in your binding.

Comment: how can call convertor in xaml

Comment: You dont 'call' the converter in the xaml you create a resource for it (and give it a key) and then use it in your binding.  I have separated the parts out so you can see them in my answer.  Note that your data context will need to notify of any changes to itself (using INotifyPropertyChanged) for the RadioButton to realise that it needs to act.

Comment: As I said you need to declare the prefix - local is only valid if have added it to the top of the file (using xmlns:local={name of assembly}.) You need to add a prefix that suits your use - i.e. if you have a namespace called converters as I normally do then: xmlns:converters={fully qualified name of namespace} will work fine.  The important thing is to have the prefix declared.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define a value converter to convert from string to boolean and use it with your `RadioButton`.

```
public class StringToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Convert.ToBool(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Convert.ToString(value);
    }
}
```

and in XAML, use

```
<RadioButton Content="visit" IsChecked="{Binding Path=type_services, Converter={StaticResource stringToBoolConverter}}"  
 FontFamily="Tahoma"/>
```

where `stringToBoolConverter` is defined in the resources of a parent element.

```
<Window.Resources> 
    <local:StringToBoolConverter x:Key="stringToBoolConverter" /> 
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: i can write this method but i don't know how to use this method in xaml.

Comment: @mo_al I have included some XAML; see if that helps.